# Query that contains all the result that has some parents in common

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm trying to query all results that has different parents in common. I need only those values.

For example we have two tables : Models and Items (and of course a link table, ItemsInModel). All items has a model and vice versa. So now I need a query to query all the common items for one or more models.

In other words, I need to use the opposite of the IN statement (because IN is using OR). We need a dynamic AND so that the query can be:

```
Select * 
from Items i 
join ItemsInModel iim on iim.itemId = i.id 
join Models m on iim.modelId = m.id 
WHERE m.id = X AND m.id = Y AND m.id = Z
```

Is there a way for query all the common items if we have a list of model ids?

Comment: Providing sample data and desired output will be very helpful

Comment: You have a column id which contains `X or Y or Z` then how can it satisfy `m.id = X AND m.id = Y AND m.id = Z`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this. It returns most common items using in all models.

```
SELECT * FROM Items i 
WHERE i.id IN (
    SELECT TOP 1 WITH TIES iim.itemId
    FROM 
        ItemsInModel iim 
    GROUP BY 
        iim.itemId
    ORDER BY COUNT(DISTINCT iim.modelId) DESC
)
```

Comment: This question helped me to create the correct query tnx.